# Linkedin token refresh doesn't return a user token but something called 'leo_auth_token'

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api

I was following [this blog post](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/tips-and-tricks-refreshing-access-token#) by one of the LinkedIn employees:

I was able to obtain a request token successfully, but the output from the authneticate endpoint gave me no upgraded token, but only something that seems like the headers of the response:

```
Array
(
    [http_code] => 200
    [content_type] => text/html;charset=UTF-8
    [url] => https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=028f7ec6-1958-4678-b3a8-d16302044a02&state=
    [header_size] => 1856
    [request_size] => 442
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 1.19871
    [namelookup_time] => 5.0E-5
    [connect_time] => 0.220965
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.670871
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 18615
    [speed_download] => 15529
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.978356
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [headers_recv] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
P3P: CP="CAO DSP COR CUR ADMi DEVi TAIi PSAi PSDi IVAi IVDi CONi OUR DELi SAMi UNRi PUBi OTRi IND PHY ONL UNI PUR FIN COM NAV INT DEM CNT POL PRE"
X-LI-UUID: DBhiUXDelKFOoB3ftH7sWQ==
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: en-US
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Mon, 04 Nov 2013 09:51:12 GMT
X-Li-Fabric: PROD-ELA4
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.linkedin.com
Set-Cookie: _lipt=deleteMe; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: leo_auth_token="GST:Uk7Zzwx4o3DYXFK1qbelLVdblluVSJf1pleK7xxCokGHRJTn_Cp6w-:1383558672:dea96f229228bd275df9209719539c4e39a4d8f9"; Version=1; Max-Age=1799; Expires=Mon, 04-Nov-2013 10:21:11 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: sl="delete me"; Version=1; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: sl="delete me"; Version=1; Domain=.www.linkedin.com; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: s_leo_auth_token="delete me"; Version=1; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID="ajax:1003784593606883111"; Version=1; Path=/
Set-Cookie: visit="v=1&G"; Version=1; Max-Age=63072000; Expires=Wed, 04-Nov-2015 09:51:12 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: lang="v=2&lang=en-us"; Version=1; Domain=linkedin.com; Path=/
Set-Cookie: bcookie="v=2&02c5bfa3-2725-4dfa-87b7-fb94e53694ff"; domain=.linkedin.com; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 04-Nov-2015 21:28:44 GMT
Set-Cookie: bscookie="v=1&2013110409511298f7fecd-d5cf-4b4a-8858-0b0360a85c34AQHbOIOpgxJguF5jetM44DFwg7CZZPf8"; domain=.www.linkedin.com; Path=/; Secure; Expires=Wed, 04-Nov-2015 21:28:44 GMT; HttpOnly
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Li-Pop: PROD-ELA4
Set-Cookie: X-LI-IDC=C1

)
```

Partial code, if anything is missing just ask, and I'll add it up:

```
private static $REFRESH_TOKEN_RESOURCE = 'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken?scope=r_fullprofile+rw_nus+w_messages+rw_groups+r_emailaddress+r_contactinfo+r_network';
private static $OAUTH_RESOURCE = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=';
public static $TOKEN_REFRESH_INTERVAL = 55;//5 days before expiry
public function refreshToken(){
    try{
        $requestToken = $this->getConnector()->oauthc->getRequestToken(self::$REFRESH_TOKEN_RESOURCE, '');
        $tokenData = json_decode($this->api(self::$OAUTH_RESOURCE . $requestToken['oauth_token'], OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST), true);
            echo '<pre>';
        print_r($tokenData);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        throw $e;
    }
    return $tokenData;
}

//main:
if($mediaConnection instanceof LinkedInConnection && $db->getTimeSinceLastTokenUpdate($userId, $mediaId) >= LinkedInConnection::$TOKEN_REFRESH_INTERVAL){
                // exit('here');
                try{
                    $mediaConnection->setTokensToDefault();
                    $tokenData = $mediaConnection->refreshToken();
                    $mediaConnection->setAccessToken($tokenData[USER_TOKENS_COLUMN_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN]);
                    $mediaConnection->setAccessTokenSecret($tokenData['oauth_token_secret']);
                    $db->setUserTokens($userId, $mediaId, $mediaConnection->getAccessToken(), $mediaConnection->getAccessTokenSecret());
                }
                catch(Exception $e){
                    $mediaConnection->setTokensToDefault();
                    $returnQueryString = Utils::addQueryParameter($returnQueryString, INPUT_KEY_NAME_SAVE_TOKENS_TO_DB_MARKER, Utils::INPUT_VALUE_DEFAULT);
                    $returnQueryString = Utils::addQueryParameter($returnQueryString, INPUT_KEY_NAME_TEMPORERALY_SAVE_TOKENS_TO_DB_MARKER, Utils::INPUT_VALUE_DEFAULT);
                    $mediaConnection->authenticate($returnQueryString);//Redirect use to login, seemless refresh required valid token + logged in user, O.
                }
}
```

Please advice,
Oleg.